# How to use Facebook API to download public company pages for information?

Tags: facebook, excel, facebook-fql, vba

As part of a project for my IT Seminar class, we have all been assigned to create different parts of a text analytic tool. There are several of us working on each part and we are able to collaborate if needed.

We are required to build the front-end in Excel and for my specific part I need to access public company information from Facebook. It was suggested to use the Facebook API for this task. The company name would be listed in a single cell and the branch-finding must be automated.

Here is the description of what I need to accomplish with this script:

Output all facebook handles (page IDs) for all branches of the company - e.g. "Hilton, New York", "Hilton New York Fashion District", etc... For the Applebee's example you would find the facebook handles for all branches (locations) for Applebees.  These can often be found through brand name matching (wildcard "Hilton *") or through downloading the list of the "likes" for the parent company.  Append additional data columns with additional branch information (e.g. number of likes, number talking about this, number that were here).  Append time-stamp at top of sheet so the data gathering time is known.

I don't have any experience with the Facebook-API or FQL so any help in getting started would be much appreciated. I have some knowledge of VBA and PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like your prof has ever worked with the Facebook API.

You've got two options if you must use Facebook:

1. Using the Graph API search functionality: `/search?q=hilton&type=page`. You'll have to filter out "Paris Hilton", "Hilton Head Island", etc. on your own.
2. Using FQL: `SELECT username, page_id, categories FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("hilton")`. In this case, you *might* be able to filter out Paris by using `categories`, if the page owner has populated these. You are also relying on the undocumented `CONTAINS()` method, which could change or stop working at any time.

If it were me, I'd approach this differently:

- I'd use data from the [Factual Places API](http://www.factual.com/data-apis/places) to find the business locations. Factual is indexed for searching and has standard categories.
- Once you've found the places, you can get the Facebook ID through the Factual Crosswalk table.
- Both these tables are available for download to work with it locally, which should be much easier in VBA/Excel.
- Once you are done, **then** query Facebook for the specific data you need.